# Efficient way of creating this component?

Tags: reactjs

***Description:***
I'm a novice at reactJS and Javascript in general.
I'm creating a component whereby I'm grabbing 5 social media icons (Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn, Twitter, Github) and creating a simple component whereby they become clickable buttons that are sourced to my social media sites.

I'm capable of it, however I'm certain there is a much more concise way of creating this component, I'm just not knowledgable of how to do so.

***Question***
What is the most efficient way creating this component?

For example, can I reduce the amount importing calls as well as button tag creations?

***Code***

```
import {BsTwitter} from "react-icons/bs"
import {FaFacebookF} from "react-icons/fa"
import {FaInstagram} from "react-icons/fa"
import {FaLinkedinIn} from "react-icons/fa"
import {BsGithub} from "react-icons/bs"

export default function Icons(){

  return(
    <div className = "icons">
      <button>
        <BsTwitter/>
      </button>
      <button>
        <FaFacebookF/>
      </button>
      <button>
        <FaInstagram/>
      </button>
      <button>
        <FaLinkedinIn/>
      </button>
      <button>
        <BsGithub/>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried creating an array and using the spread operator, however, I think I'm clearly doing somethign wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good as is, but if you have a lot of these icons, you can clean it up by dynamically lazy loading them. Bear in mind this increases the complexity. Additionally, you'll still need to have a map of the icon names and the path to the exported module (since they can be from different modules)

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cartwright-5vgt3k?file=/src/App.js, but will paste below as well:

```
import "./styles.css";

import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

const icons = [
  { BsTwitter: "bs" },
  { FaFacebookF: "fa" },
  { FaInstagram: "fa" }
];
const components = icons.map((icon) => {
  const { 0: name, 1: path } = Object.entries(icon)[0];

  // react.lazy only imports default export, so let's remap the default
  return lazy(() =>
    import(`react-icons/${path}`).then((module) => ({ default: module[name] }))
  );
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}></Suspense>
      <div className="icons">
        {components.map((Component) => (
          <button>
            <Component />
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cartwright-5vgt3k?file=/src/App.js
```

Comment: This looks awsome, although I'll be honest I don't know half of what you type. I'll keep this as a reference as I lern more react and JS thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ButtonList component. This will save you time if you ever need to change what wraps the icons. Here is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-platform-7zn7rq?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function ButtonList({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
        return <button>{React.cloneElement(child)}</button>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
    
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <ButtonList>
        <BsTwitter />
        <FaFacebookF />
        <FaInstagram />
        <BsGithub />
        <FaLinkedinIn />
      </ButtonList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will map over the children (your icons) and render each of them as a button.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution. I still think it's a bit repetative though

Comment: @JahiZamy I get you. I think no matter how you do it, you'll need to import those icons and render them. Your goal, IMO, should change from "I want less code in the component" to "What's the most scalable way to build the component". So that if you need to go back and refactor how the icons are rendered or what the button does, you're just changing it in one place.